# How to display some objects of model B that has a ForeignKey pointing to model A,in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, foreign-keys

Here's my models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    auther = models.ForeignKey("Person")
```

When I'm in a certain Person in django admin,I want to see all the Books written by this Person.How can this be achieved?
Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline]
```

Comment: Thank you,it works!And sorry to bother,I should've check the document more carefully.